# Swift: Creating a button that shuffles an array

Tags: arrays, swift, boolean

I am trying to create an UIAlertAction that is displayed after clicking on a sort button, that would shuffle the array. I tried this:

```
let action4 = UIAlertAction(title: "Shuffle", style: .default) { ( action: UIAlertAction) in self.array.sort { self.array.shuffle() }
    self.tableView.reloadData() }
```

I used that to sort by names:

```
let action = UIAlertAction(title: "By name", style: .default) { ( action: UIAlertAction) in self.array.sort { $1.first_name > $0.first_name }
        self.tableView.reloadData() }
```

Error: `Cannot convert value of type '[Person]' to expected argument type 'Bool'`

Comment: `self.array.sort { self.array.shuffle() }` what does it mean for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove `sort`, you don't want sorting, you want shuffling only.

```
let action4 = UIAlertAction(title: "Shuffle", style: .default) { _ in self.array.shuffle() }
```

Comment: Nice but I didnt't understand why for my other buttons I had to use sort

Comment: What mean sort for you? It means "ordering". So why would you want to sort and shuffle at the same time? They are opposite, no?

Comment: @catrev `sort` takes a `Bool` comparing 2 consecutive elements and deciding the order of the array based on the return value of comparing each value. On the other hand, `shuffle` already reorders the array - it gives a random order. Ordering an array and sorting isn't the same. Sorting uses a specific rule for comparing elements, while ordering doesn't - ordering can be random, which is the case for `shuffle`.

Comment: Hmm I see. What are the other functions like this ? And why use shuffle() instead of shuffled()

Comment: @catrev what other functions? These are completely independent functions, so it's hard to say what other ones are like these...

Comment: `shuffle` vs `shuffled`: On is applying the effect one the object, it's a mutating func, the other one is returning a version for it.